# "This Mac can't connect to iCloud" popup

Tags: icloud, apple-id

When I downloaded an app from the App Store, the message "This Mac can't connect to iCloud because of a problem with XXX" popped up, where XXX is my Apple ID. There are two buttons: "Apple ID Preferences" and "Later".

I have chosen the former, entered my Apple ID password, and got on the Apple ID preferences page. However, I don't know what I should change there, and why this message pops up in the first place. Downloading the app worked without problems. I also verified via Finder, that I can access my iCloud drive.

What is this message telling me, and what can I do to avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

I've never been sure if this is intentional, a temporary connectivity interruption or just a glitch. Often simply re-entering the password in the Prefs is enough to clear it. Occasionally I've know it ask again.
It usually 'just goes away' after a time.

(Pure speculation. If anyone knows a clearer reason, this answer can go away again;)

Comment: It's creepy! I would not expect this from Apple. Had it today 3 times in a row. Glad that I'm not the only one with this experience, but utmost strange that there doesn't seem to be a logical explanation.

Comment: Hmmm… just loaded up iTunes [I'm still on an old Mac] that I use daily & it not only asked me for a password, but also threw the 2FA routine to my phone. In effect it seems to have completely lost the previous 'trust'. Having successfully completed that… it asked me the password again. Maybe something did properly glitch at Apple today…